# how to add something like infowindow on google visualization "geochart" when marker is selected?

Tags: infowindow, google-visualization

my attempt to add an infowindow on geochart result in failure as infowindow need to add something like an anchor , which in geochart's documentation don't specify how to add those , and after hours searching on google nothing show up. is it possible to add infowindow on geochart? if yes how to do that? or there is a way to get the position of the marker? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible. 
Also, the geochart api is one of the few from the visualization API that does not accept HTML for the tooltips, but I hope they change that soon.

Also, from my experience, you can only get the position of the marker (or any other info related to the marker) if you use that info to build the marker. For example, if you use lat/lon values to build the marker, you can get those values on click.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but is it possible to add html class on marker ? and is x,y of the marker the same as lng lat?

Comment: if x,y is the position of the mouse on the screen, it will be different from lat/long. you can't add html class to the marker, but you can apply some css, but with limitations doing a class for svg circle { stroke:"#cccccc"; stroke-width:1px; fill:#16a61e; } for example.